# Domino Offers SSL3.0 instead of TLS for Outgoing connection to WebService

Tags: web-services, ssl, lotus-domino

I have problem understanding Dominos behavour to offer SSL or TLS for outgoing connections to WebService.

We have an agent that access a WebService.
The WebService only accepts TLS 1.0

From time to time the connection crashes and
I turned on DEBUG_SSL_ALL=3 to see what is happening

I figured out that the connection fails due to the server offers SSLV3.0 instead of TLS1.0, see example in the log at 05:45:58

How can the server suddenly do that ?
I read in another post that this sometimes can happen due to "resumption" that should be some behaviour to remember and connect faster.
That sounds like good thing to have but in this case it does not seams to be the reason. I have this agent to run on its own for a couple of hours and it suddenly changes protocoll anyway.

Our server needs to keep the ability to use SSL for other reasons
So I cant do the DISABLE_SSLV3=1 for the moment and the receiving server cant use SSL.

Here is my log hope for some help
The start of the connection is identical as I see it, is there anymore smart debug statements that can give me more ?

```
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.36 PM SSLInitContext> 0 Available cipherspec: 0x0035
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.36 PM SSLInitContext> 1 Available cipherspec: 0x002F
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.36 PM SSLInitContext> 2 Available cipherspec: 0x000A
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.36 PM SSLInitContext> 3 Available cipherspec: 0x0005
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.36 PM int_MapSSLError> Mapping SSL error 0 to 0     [SSLNoErr]
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.36 PM SSL_Handshake> Enter
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.36 PM SSL_Handshake> Current Cipher 0x0000 (Unknown Cipher)
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.36 PM SSL_Handshake> outgoing ->protocolVersion: 0301
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.36 PM SSLAdvanceHandshake Enter> Processed : 0 State: 4 (HandshakeClientIdle)
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.38 PM SSLAdvanceHandshake Enter> Processed : SSL_hello_request
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.38 PM SSLAdvanceHandshake calling SSLPrepareAndQueueMessage> SSLEncodeClientHello
[10A4:000C-082C] 01/13/2016 05:26:59.38 PM SSLEncodeClientHello> We offered SSL/TLS version TLS1.0 (0x0301)
...
[1204:0006-1390] 01/13/2016 05:28:59.91 PM SSLEncodeClientHello> We offered SSL/TLS version TLS1.0 (0x0301)
...
[10A4:000F-08BC] 01/13/2016 05:29:54.78 PM SSLEncodeClientHello> We offered SSL/TLS version TLS1.0 (0x0301)
...
[0F38:000B-0BCC] 01/13/2016 05:36:03.58 PM SSLEncodeClientHello> We offered SSL/TLS version TLS1.0 (0x0301)
...
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.19 PM SSLInitContext> 0 Available cipherspec: 0x0035
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.19 PM SSLInitContext> 1 Available cipherspec: 0x002F
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.19 PM SSLInitContext> 2 Available cipherspec: 0x000A
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.19 PM SSLInitContext> 3 Available cipherspec: 0x0005
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.21 PM int_MapSSLError> Mapping SSL error 0 to 0     [SSLNoErr]
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.21 PM SSL_Handshake> Enter
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.21 PM SSL_Handshake> Current Cipher 0x0000 (Unknown Cipher)
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.21 PM SSL_Handshake> outgoing ->protocolVersion: 0301
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.21 PM SSLAdvanceHandshake Enter> Processed : 0 State: 4 (HandshakeClientIdle)
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.21 PM SSLAdvanceHandshake Enter> Processed : SSL_hello_request
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.21 PM SSLAdvanceHandshake calling SSLPrepareAndQueueMessage> SSLEncodeClientHello
[1204:0009-0A94] 01/13/2016 05:45:58.21 PM SSLEncodeClientHello> We offered SSL/TLS version SSLV3.0 (0x0300)
...
[10A4:0012-08A0] 01/13/2016 05:50:59.42 PM SSLEncodeClientHello> We offered SSL/TLS version TLS1.0 (0x0301)
...
[10A4:0015-0DF4] 01/13/2016 05:52:23.57 PM SSLEncodeClientHello> We offered SSL/TLS version TLS1.0 (0x0301)
...
[10A4:0018-090C] 01/13/2016 05:53:33.55 PM SSLEncodeClientHello> We offered SSL/TLS version TLS1.0 (0x0301)
```

/Stefan

Comment: I suggest to post on server fault.

Comment: When posting this question at server fault where it belongs please post EXACT Server version (including fixpack) as this effects the way that Domino can communicate (TLS 1.0 is only available for the newest fixpack of 8.5.3, TLS 1.2 is available for 9.0.1FP4 and above)

Comment: Sorry, server version is Domino 9.0.1 FP4

Comment: I'm a little confused here. You're talking about an agent running on Domino making an outbound call to a web service. If that's what it is, it seems to me that it is a StackOverflow question, but you haven't shown the code. Then again, you turned on DEBUG_SSL_ALL, so I think you're saying that the web service is running on Domino, so your outbound call from the agent is just looping back to the Domino server. Is that correct?

Comment: There is no need to showing code, the code works perfect

The Domino agent is running and connecting to a external WebService, act as a client, the only strange thing here is why Domino suddenly Offers a SSL3.0 connection, it seams to be random.

The agent runs like every 5 minute